# Prove directly from the definition that $\lim: \lim_{x\to -2} x^2 + x - 5 = -3$

Tags: calculus, limits, quadratics, epsilon-delta

So I am a bit stuck on applying the limit definition for this problem. This is what I have so far:

$\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta $ then $\lvert f(x) - l \rvert < \epsilon$$ $$\lvert x + 2 \rvert < \delta$ $$\lvert x^2 + x -2 \rvert < \epsilon $$

which means $\lvert x -1 \rvert \lvert x + 2 \rvert < \epsilon $

$\lvert x + 2 \rvert < {\epsilon\over \lvert x -1 \rvert} $

let $\delta = 1 $ then: $\lvert x + 2 \rvert < \delta < 1 $ which means 
$-1 < x -1 < 1 $
$-4 < x -1 < -2 $
Thus the upper bound of $\lvert x -1 \rvert < -2 $ is $-2$

let $$\delta = \min(1, {\epsilon\over -2}) $$

But what is confusing me here is the fact that, how is $ \lvert x + 2 \rvert < {\epsilon\over -2} $

Because if $\epsilon$ is any number more than $0$, then ${\epsilon\over -2} $ will be negative and it can't be greater than $ \lvert x + 2 \rvert $.

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}x^2+x-5-(-3)&=x^2-4+x+2\\&=(x-2)(x+2)+x+2\\&=(x-1)(x+2).\end{align}So, if $\lvert x+2\rvert<1$, then $\lvert x-1\rvert\leqslant\lvert x+2\rvert+3<4$. So, take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon4\right\}$. Then, if $\lvert x+2\rvert<\delta$, then$$\lvert x^2+x-5-(-3)\rvert<4\frac\varepsilon4=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: how did you get $|x -2|$ shouldn't it be $|x +2|$ ?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: All good. But I am still confused. Why did you add 3?

Comment: Triangle inequality:\begin{align}\lvert x-1\rvert&=\lvert x+2-3\rvert\\&\leqslant\lvert x+2\rvert+\lvert-3\rvert\\&=\lvert x+2\rvert+3.\end{align}

Comment: That makes sense. I am just confused about how to approach a problem as such. Like there are so many different ways like triangle of inequality or the way I tried to do it. Is it just trial and error until you get an upper bound? Also do you mind explaining why we need to make $|x - 1| = |x + 2 -3| $

Comment: If I choose a small $\delta$, then $\lvert x+2\rvert$ will be small but, in principle, $\lvert x-1\rvert$ could be very large. So, I have to prove that it dooesn't become *too* large. That's why I do $\lvert x-1\rvert=\lvert x+2-3\rvert\leqslant\lvert x+2\rvert+3$: to make sure that $\lvert x-1\rvert$ isn't too large.